# URL Modification for category pages in opencart

Tags: php, opencart2.x

WE are working with opencart for website and i have problem with category pages url , when i am giving unique url for a category using admin panel or bulk data upload using export/import toll for categories it is not working properly and on the front end it is showing category not found or page not found error.I tried deleting duplicate url's in oc_url_alias table and also i am providing unique url for the category when i am creating a new one.
We have subcategories under main category and if i am trying to add url for any subcategory then also the category pages are throwing some error , can anyone suggest a way to solve this because i don't want the custom url path which will come for categories in opencart like (www.domain.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=1_2) and we are trying to add seo freindly urls for all the pages

Answer (score 0):

Hope you enabled seo url from admin and renamed htaccess.txt to .htaccess in root dir

and if still not working, must be issue with your export / import extension

if there is 2 values for single category id in database, it will also through error

Comment: Yes , seo url was enabled and htaccess was renamed to .htaccess.